# how do you populate sql query result in a textbox or input control like google search dropdown result

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i'm doing a small project for a friend any help would be great thank you in advance.

i have a textbox however i can use a html input control as well.

same idea as google bar where you able to type a letter a which will return any description match with letter a. It would show matching values underneath the inut control same as goodle search bar.

Any ideas how to do this code example C# would be great thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery and an HTTP handler

1. Download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)(If you don't already have it)
2. Download [autocomplete.js](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/lib/jquery.autocomplete.js)
3. Download [jquery.autocomplete.css](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/lib/jquery.autocomplete.css)
4. Copy the files to your project.Mine are in sub folders called Scripts and Style

**SQL:**

For the sake of example I've created a local database called Search which has one table with two columns SearchId and Search to store some dummy search data

**ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Auto complete</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Style/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete("Autocomplete.ashx");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="txtSearch" type="text" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Autocomplete.ashx handler:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication17
{
    public class Autocomplete : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
            string input = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
            string query = "SELECT TOP 10 Search FROM Search WHERE Search LIKE '" + input + "%'";

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                            context.Response.Write(reader.GetString(0) + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get{return false;}
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I've placed the zipped version of the project on [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iPiW5jXDdPOTFIbzJqWVNHMlk/edit).Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it will help a lot :)